# DataTable, SQLDataAdapter и автоинкремент

Tags: c#, база-данных, wpf

Пытаюсь обеспечить взаимодействие своего DataGrid с бд SQLite стандартными, вроде как, механиками:

```
private void mainTabControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Main", _connection);
        MainCommandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(MainAdapter);
        MainAdapter.Fill(MainTable);
        mainGrid.DataContext = MainTable.DefaultView;

        FillMainDeptComboBox();

        MainTable.TableNewRow += (o, args) =>
        { 
            MainAdapter.Update(MainTable);
        };
        MainTable.RowChanged += (o, args) =>
        {
            MainAdapter.Update(MainTable);
        };
    }
```

Отредактированные строки исправно транслируются в бд. Проблемы возникают, когда в DataGrid создается и добавляется новая строка, а затем при попытке её редактировать получаю: System.Data.DBConcurrencyException. Очевидно, это происходит из-за наличия в таблице бд столбца "id" с автоинкрементом. Имею примерное представление, каким образом вручную подсовывать в DataTable это значение, но прежде хотелось бы узнать, существуют ли заготовленные средства для этого?

Comment: Вам не кажется, что если грузить базу данных в память в конструкторе контрола, то при этом ваше приложение будет безбожно тормозить? (А потом жалуются, что современные программы медленнее, чем старые.)

Comment: @VladD, согласен с Вами, так и есть. Просто на время разбора полетов мне гораздо удобнее выделить только целевой участок кода, который гарантированно вызывает проблему, независимо от наличия Task'ов или других средств устранения залипаний.

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Это первый на моей памяти хороший и конструктивный ответ на такое замечание.

Comment: @Pavel  после вызова `MainAdapter.Fill(MainTable);` какое значение возвращает `MainTable.Columns["id"].AutoIncrement`?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос довольно интересный. В первую очередь, в sqlite автоинкремент отключён по умолчанию. У вас он включён? )

Для использования автоинкрементальных id обычно не нужно передавать ничего в поле Id при вставке записей. Возможно, у вас там значение, отличное от "айди по умолчанию"

Из документации SQLite:

The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.

In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed integer.

On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.

If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows.